# Android camera app that can record sound while recording slow motion video

Tags: android, video, camera, audio-recording

I tried using stock camera app to record slow motion videos, but the app is not recording audio in slow motion mode. There is no audio at all, it's just mute.

I would like to record audio too while recording slow motion video. I know sound will be distorted but I would like to record distorted sound instead of no sound.

**So which Android app can record audio in slow motion video recording?**

The only thing required is 1080p 60FPS recording with audio.

It can either be free or paid, it does not matter. I have a OnePlus One using latest Cyanogen OS.

Comment: I would focus on video editing instead of recording with special features. It is much easier to edit a video than to apply filters while recording. This will you will be able to stretch the audio or add a different audio track as you please.

Comment: We usually can't capture higher frequencies due to technical limitations in audio chips. When we discuss recording in slow motion, it involves capturing the regular sound and processing it either during or immediately after recording to slow it down. This could be considered a feature request for an existing camera with a slow-motion capability. However, it's worth noting that implementing this is not a trivial task, as it requires various complex algorithms, especially if we aim for high-quality results.

Answer (score 0):

I have a smartphone from BQ with the [BQ camera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bq.camerabq&hl=en_US) version 4.12.5, which also seems to be available for everyone. I just tested it and there is definitely sound (distorted) while playing back a slow motion video.

The app mentions that it is based on the Camera2 API from Google. Maybe other apps also being based on that API offer the same functionality.

Comment: Not compatible with Xiaomi, as it seems to me :(